# how to keep menu open by default in the dynamic css menu

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

What should i change in the css to make the menu open by default in the following dynamic css menu:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/responsive_iconic_menu/

I removed `left: -100%; /* hide menu intially */` but that didn't do it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.iconicmenu ul {
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 1;
}
```